# How to substitute path to home for "~"?

Tags: clojure

If I pass in a path from the command line, "~" expands to my home directory:

```
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (doseq [arg args]
    (println arg)))

britannia:uberjar srseverance$ java -jar args-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar ~/158.clj 
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/srseverance/158.clj
```

But if I try to use a path-file containing ~, I can't find the file.

```
user> (with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader "~/158.clj")]
        (doall (line-seq r)))
FileNotFoundException ~/158.clj (No such file or directory)  java.io.FileInputStream.open0 (FileInputStream.java:-2)
```

How do I take a string like, "~/158.clj" and get back something `clojure.java.io/reader` can use, such as "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/srseverance/158.clj"?

Comment: As an addition to the answer below: it's the shell that expands the `~` before command is executed, that's why it does not work when you use that from your code.

Comment: As @zerkms says, this is all shell expansion. When you use the string `~/158.clj` inside clojure, it is literally looking for a file with that name, which will only work if you create a dir in your cwd called `~` and put the file 158.clj in it. You'll get similar results if you try using `*` expecting it to expand - it won't, as the shell does that before passing it to the application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define

```
(defn expand-home [s]
  (if (.startsWith s "~")
    (clojure.string/replace-first s "~" (System/getProperty "user.home"))
    s))
```

and use it to resolve home directory:

```
(clojure.java.io/reader (expand-home "~/158.clj"))]
```

You could also look into [fs](https://github.com/Raynes/fs) library definition of [expand-home](https://github.com/Raynes/fs/blob/b1e1fd68f5859c55f9afc352eab1c5229a9c549c/src/me/raynes/fs.clj#L32), which solves the `~foo` problem outlined in bfontaine's comment below:

```clj
(let [homedir (io/file (System/getProperty "user.home"))
      usersdir (.getParent homedir)]
  (defn home
    "With no arguments, returns the current value of the `user.home` system
     property. If a `user` is passed, returns that user's home directory. It
     is naively assumed to be a directory with the same name as the `user`
     located relative to the parent of the current value of `user.home`."
    ([] homedir)
    ([user] (if (empty? user) homedir (io/file usersdir user)))))

(defn expand-home
  "If `path` begins with a tilde (`~`), expand the tilde to the value
  of the `user.home` system property. If the `path` begins with a
  tilde immediately followed by some characters, they are assumed to
  be a username. This is expanded to the path to that user's home
  directory. This is (naively) assumed to be a directory with the same
  name as the user relative to the parent of the current value of
  `user.home`."
  [path]
  (let [path (str path)]
    (if (.startsWith path "~")
      (let [sep (.indexOf path File/separator)]
        (if (neg? sep)
          (home (subs path 1))
          (io/file (home (subs path 1 sep)) (subs path (inc sep)))))
      path)))
```

Comment: Note this doesn’t work with e.g. `~foo`, which is `foo`’s home directory.

Comment: @bfontaine is correct. The definition linked at the bottom handles this case properly. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing bfontaine's comment, we can get correct results for `~user` and `~root` by asking the system instead:

```
(require '[clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]])

(defn bash [command]
  (sh "bash" "-c" command))

(defn expand [path]
  (-> (str "echo -n " path)
      bash
      :out))

(expand "~")
;; => /home/teodorlu

(expand "~teodorlu")
;; => /home/teodorlu

(expand "~root")
;; => /root
```

Though, just use this for trusted code!

```
(expand "`cat ~/.passwords`")
;; => All my passwords!
```